# How to run "ert" tests?

Tags: ert

What I tried:

```
Cloned a package with ert tests (https://github.com/dgutov/robe )
# sidenote this package was previously installed using use-package
emacs ~/robe/core-tests.el
M-x ert
```

> Selector: t Passed:  0 Failed:  0 Skipped: 0 Total:   0/0 Started at: 
>   2019-11-10 12:31:14-0800 Finished. Finished at:  2019-11-10
>   12:31:14-0800

This feels wrong because obviously the package has more than 0 tests.

Also btw: how do I run tests in "emacs -batch" mode.

Comment: `C-h i g (ert) RET`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you ran `emacs ~/robe/core-tests.el`, that opened up the file in your Emacs, right?

Then the tests themselves have to be loaded into Emacs. The `ert` tests are written in ELisp, so you need to evaluate that file. That can be done with <kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd>, or if the file is not open, you can run <kbd>M-x load-file</kbd>.

Then <kbd>M-x ert</kbd> will run those tests. Simply opening the file is not enough.

Comment: wow what a gotcha

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior - please mark the answer correct if it solved the problem.